# spl_autoload_register's different behaviour b/n online and localhost

Tags: php, closures, spl, spl-autoload-register, spl-autoloader

[image]

I have the following directory structure, I put all my classes inside `classes/` as shown below, and I have a `header.php` which both calls all files, and has other important settings that all files share.

Now, If I use `spl_autoload_register()` this way:

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class){
        include 'classes/'. $class .'.class.php';
    });
```

inside `inc/header.php` file and call this `header.php` from my `index` file, then it works fine on my localhost, but when I upload all the script as-is to a live host, then I get errors like.

```
Warning: include(classes/filehandler.class.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/.../public_html/....com/inc/header.php on line 9
```

`Line 9` is the `spl_autoload_register()`

I don't get, how this could happen, and hoping anyone has any idea at all.

thanks

Comment: is it correct the path you see after "no such file or..."? does it point to you header file?

Comment: @ilpaijin yes, it does point to the correct directory. That is whats confusing about this

Comment: You should use the absolute path not the relative one when loading classes. Also, you don't just `include` in the autoloader, you also check if the class file actually exists in your classes folder(again, absolutepath). L.E: Another note, in your current example, the autoloader looks for a `classes` folder inside the `inc` folder and this is happening because you use relative paths, so again, go with absolute paths(`__FILE__`, `__DIR__` should help you).

Comment: try to call get_include_path(), and check if there is something wrong

Comment: @Twisted1919 How would absolute be possible at all? you mean reference it from the `c:/` folder, or by `http://` ? BTW: the example I used it shown here as a proper usage http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php ?

Comment: @Twisted1919 Can you give me an example? or write it in the answer? I really need to see how this works.

Comment: or try to check permission it could be something related

Comment: check the predefined constants i shown you. For example, `echo dirname(__FILE__)` should give you the full path to the directory containing your file where this code resides. I believe `echo __DIR__` will do the same on php >= 5.3

Comment: @ilpaijin Giving it a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show what i mean with my comments, add this code in your index.php file and remove the autoloader from your other files:

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class){
    $classesPath = dirname(__FILE__) . '/classes/';
    if (is_file($classFile = $classesPath . $class.'.class.php')) {
        include $classFile;
    }
});
```

For inc/header.php:

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class){
    $classesPath = dirname(__FILE__) . '/../classes/';
    if (is_file($classFile = $classesPath . $class.'.class.php')) {
        include $classFile;
    }
});
```

Comment: @Twisted1919is right. Always check for file existence as a common practice

Comment: @Twisted1919 I would give this a try, but I have more than 13 files in the root directory besides the `index.php` file. So, your method dictates I add it inside all those files. So, the only convenient approach is to add it in the `inc/header.php` and only call this file in all the rest

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I am trying different combinations of methods to find the files, but I still get the same error

Comment: @Xlaltra - if you `echo realpath($classesPath);` in your autoloader, what does it says?

Comment: I get `/home/example/public_html/mysite.com/classes` which is a seems to be the dir from which I am trying to load my classes in @Twisted1919

Comment: I also did `get_include_path()` and I am getting exactly this: `.:/usr/local/altphp/lib/php` Not sure, if there is something wrong with it or not

Comment: @Xlaltra in this case there is something else wrong with your code, the autoloader is fine. Please note that linux is case sensitive, so if you have the file `filehandler.class.php`, the class declaration must be `class filehandler {...}` and you will call it with `new filehandler()`. Other than that, you will have to recheck your code.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will do some re-checking. Everything seems to be fine, I just don't understand this error when I visit `index.php` I get `Warning: include(/home/example/public_html/mysite.com/classes) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such device in /home/example/public_html/mysite.com/inc/includes.php on line 11` 
You see that `/inc/` it should not happen since I am calling the script from `index.php`

Comment: Neah, post your index.php file here. Also where do you call your includes.php file? what does it contains ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41332/discussion-between-twisted1919-and-xlaltra)